# In angular JS - How to check username is email or text for login page

Tags: angularjs

Hi I am fresh to angular js, I want to create a login page using angular js.

I have created the login page using templates.

**Issue i am facing is.....**

I am having a field as "Email id/ username".

So I need to validate the value is email id or name.

The code I done is

**login.view.html**

```
<form name="form" ng-submit="vm.login()" role="form">
        <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error': form.username.$dirty && form.username.$error.required }">
            <label for="username">Email/UserName</label>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Email/UserName" name="username" id="username" class="form-control" ng-model="vm.username" required />
            <span ng-show="form.username.$dirty && form.username.$error.required" class="help-block">Email or username required</span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error': form.password.$dirty && form.password.$error.required }">
            <label for="password">Password</label>
            <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="form-control" placeholder="password" ng-model="vm.password" required />
            <span ng-show="form.password.$dirty && form.password.$error.required" class="help-block">Password  required</span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-actions">
            <button type="submit" ng-disabled="form.$invalid || vm.dataLoading" class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
```

**controller.html :**

```
    (function () {
        'use strict';

        var app=angular
            .module('app');


         app.directive('usernamevalidation', function() {

              var REQUIRED_PATTERNS = [/^[^\s@]+@[^\s@]+\.[^\s@]{2,}$/];

              return {
                require : 'ngModel',
                scope:  {
                    usernamevalidation: '='
                },
                link : function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
                  scope.$watch(function())  {
                     var combined;

                    if(scope.usernamevalidation || ctrl.$viewValue)  {
                      <!-- Here I need to do validation -->
                  }

                 }
                  }; 
                }
              }
            });

        app.controller('LoginController', LoginController);

        LoginController.$inject = ['$location', 'AuthenticationService', 'FlashService'];

        function LoginController($location, AuthenticationService, FlashService) {
            var vm = this;

            vm.login = login;    

            (function initController() {
                // reset login status
                AuthenticationService.ClearCredentials();
            })();


            function login() {
                vm.dataLoading = true;

               if (email_id == true) {
                AuthenticationService.Login(vm.username, vm.password, function (response) {
                    if (response.json.response.statuscode == 0) {
                        AuthenticationService.SetCredentials(vm.username, vm.password);
                        $location.path('/');
                    }           
                    else {
                        FlashService.Error(response.json.response.statusmessage);
                        vm.dataLoading = false;
                    }
                });
}
else if (email_id == false)
{
                AuthenticationService.adminLogin(vm.username, vm.password, function (response) {
                    if (response.json.response.statuscode == 0) {
                        AuthenticationService.SetCredentials(vm.username, vm.password);
                        $location.path('/');
                    }       
    }    
                    else {
                        FlashService.Error(response.json.response.statusmessage);
                        vm.dataLoading = false;
                    }
                });
            };
        }

    })();
```

If the user input is email id then i need to enter into "`AuthenticationService.Login`" method.
else if it is username then i need to enter into "`AuthenticationService.adminLogin`" method else if not both then I will show error.

Before, I was using only "`AuthenticationService.Login`" method but now i need to check a condition before entering into any method.

Can anyone please help me how i need to do.

Comment: why don't  you just create another method in your controller, submite your form to it, and then check whether user provided a username or an email. Then based on results call `AuthenticationService.Login` or `AuthenticationService.adminLogin` manually in this method.

Comment: I have created a method "app.directive('usernamevalidation', function()" to check it is an email_id or username in controller but missing code to check  it is an email_id or name. So can please help me what code i need to use to validate user input.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if your `username` contains `@` symbol or not. If it does than user provided an email and validate it as an email otherwise validate it as a username. Also same check can be used in your login method like this:

```
function login() {
    vm.dataLoading = true;

    if (vm.username.indexOf('@') != -1) {
        AuthenticationService.Login(vm.username, vm.password, function(response) {
            if (response.json.response.statuscode == 0) {
                AuthenticationService.SetCredentials(vm.username, vm.password);
                $location.path('/');
            } else {
                FlashService.Error(response.json.response.statusmessage);
                vm.dataLoading = false;
            }
        });
    } else {
        AuthenticationService.adminLogin(vm.username, vm.password, function(response) {
            if (response.json.response.statuscode == 0) {
                AuthenticationService.SetCredentials(vm.username, vm.password);
                $location.path('/');
            } else {
                FlashService.Error(response.json.response.statusmessage);
                vm.dataLoading = false;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you I got it